# Is there a way to check if anything is on a line in a text file, and if so write to the next line instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Because of how text files work, i need to know how to find (if there is a way) if there is anything on a line, and if so i need it so that it starts writing the next line. I was using a for loop and writing to a text file using an iterative, but it only writes the first thing it finds. Here is the code:

```
names = ['Clemont', 'Albert', 'Shiro']
    for x in range(len(names)):
        file = open('file.txt', 'w')
        file.write(names[x])
```

I need it to write all the names to the text file but it only seems to want to write 'Albert'. I thought i understood what was happening, being that it rewrites the text file every time it moves to the next name, but then why does it not say 'Shiro' since that's the last name in the list to be written in? Essentially i just want to write the names to individual names in the text file but i've little idea of what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're opening and file every time in the write mode, it deletes the previous contents of the file and adds in the new content. You want to use the append mode, which will automatically write it on the next line.

```
names = ['Clement', 'Albert', 'Shiro']
for name in names:
    with open('file.txt','a') as f:
        f.write(name + '\n')
```

It's better practice to use `with` when you're performing file operations since it automatically closes the file

You can also only open the file once (thanks kindall):

**This is the better option**

```
names = ['Clement', 'Albert', 'Shiro']
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    for name in names:
        f.write(name+'\n')
```

Comment: I still dont understand why it had Albert in the text file? Surely it should say Shiro since thats the last name and thus it overwrites anything that was previously in there?

Comment: Should have `with open...` first, and the `for` underneath. Then, open the file in `'w'` mode.